# Finding probability of a data point in WEKA Clustering (EM)

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, weka

Which method is used to determine the probability of a data belonging to a cluster point using EM Clustering algorithm  in WEKA?

Comment: It is open-source. Use the source.

Answer (score 1):

The [distributionForInstance](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/clusterers/AbstractDensityBasedClusterer.html#distributionForInstance(weka.core.Instance)) function should be what you're looking for.